# how should I write my node script for minimal memory usage when inserting large numbers of records to a database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

Let's say I want to generate a million records and insert them to a database. If it takes an hour, no problem.

I've got a library that generates fake retail data:

`var records = retailGen.generateOrders(numberOfRecords);`

OK that's no problem, it can generate a million records fairly quickly. The problem comes when I queue up a large number of records and loop over them (every record contains one or more transactions, insertTransaction is an async call to the db):

```
  _fn = function(record) {
    var transaction, _j, _len, _ref, _results;
    _ref = record.transactions; 
    for (_j = 0, _len = _ref.length; _j < _len; _j++) {
      transaction = _ref[_j];
      insertTransaction(transaction); 
    } 
  };

  for (n = _i = 0; 0 <= runs ? _i < runs : _i > runs; n = 0 <= runs ? ++_i : --_i) {
    _fn(records[n]);
  }
```

It will pile all those async calls up and swamp the memory, eventually choking the OS to the point that I can't do anything. I'd like to know how more experienced js programmers approach this problem. The script works, but poorly when the numbers get large.

I'd prefer to solve this with pure js instead of a library -- it'll be a better learning experience. I considered putting the insert of the next record in the "done" callback of the first insert but then it feels like I'm forcing node to be sychronous (well, sorta synchronous).

Answer (score 0):

When I insert "hard collected" large data amounts first I tend to give them to a php scipt, chunk up into even parts, and put it into a file.

Now this may sound waste of resources but you can virtually not go wrong with serializing data. So up till this point nothing can break. I assume with collecting huge amounts of data you can get unexpected "things".

Than I get the serialized file line-by-line, unserialize and insert it.

If anything should break in the middle: I have the data to reproduce the error, and no data loss can occur.

I can put sleep tospare CPU, limit the amount of data in the chunks.

This is how I go about it.

Comment: Yeah that's similar to what I did: I just put a loop in a bash script and called the node script. Don't like that solution, feels like I should be able to do this better.

Comment: Better like faster or what do you mean? What is your goal with better?

Comment: Without resorting to bash scripts etc. I want to know how to do this sort of rate limiting in node.

Comment: Well I think if you insert huge amounts of data, you can do it fast and CPU consuming, or slow and sparing. put sleep in between inserting chunks (or set interval in js) and use smaller sizes if you want to go under the radar:)